# Facebook Insights get_insights_async not fetching all Insights for certain accounts

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-insights

I am using the below code to pull data for insights of every active account. The problem I am seeing is that the api is not fetching insights for action_values, video_thruplay for certain accounts. For example if I have 270 active accounts out of which 25 have these insights, the api is showing me results for only 5. I tried everything like reducing date_range, fields but it's not working. I tried pulling the same using the sync method get_insights and that is able to pull these insights for all accounts. I even played around with the limit parameters to no avail.

```
def wait_for_async_job(job):
    for _ in range(TIMEOUT):
        time.sleep(1)
        job = job.api_get()
        status = job[AdReportRun.Field.async_status]
        if status == "Job Completed":
            return job.get_result(params={"limit": 1000})


me = User(fbid='me')
platform_insights_async=[]
ad_accounts = me.get_ad_accounts(fields=['id', 'account_status'])
count = 0
TIMEOUT=300

for ad_account in ad_accounts:
    if ad_account['status'] ==  1 : 
        fields = ['account_id','account_currency','account_name','campaign_id','campaign_name','adset_id','adset_name','ad_id','actions','action_values','ad_name', 'objective','clicks','spend','video_thruplay_watched_actions','impressions']
        params = {
            'date_preset': 'last_28d',
            'time_increment': 1,
            'level': 'ad',
            'breakdowns': ['publisher_platform'],
            'filtering':[{'field':'ad.impressions','operator': 'GREATER_THAN','value': '0'},{'field':'action_type','operator': 'IN','value': ['purchase','post_engagement','omni_app_install']}],
            'use_unified_attribution_setting':True,
        }
        ad_insights_platform = ad_account.get_insights_async(fields=fields, params=params)
        result_cursor = wait_for_async_job(ad_insights_platform)
        results = [item for item in result_cursor]
        for insight in results:
                try:
                    insight_action=str(insight['actions'])
                except Exception as ex:
                        print(f"actions not available. {ex}")
                        insight_action=''
                try:
                    insight_action_value=str(insight['action_values'])
                except Exception as ex:
                        print(f"action_values not available. {ex}")
                        insight_action_value=''
                try:
                    insight_thruplay=str(insight['video_thruplay_watched_actions']['action_type'=='video_view']['value'])
                except Exception as ex:
                        print(f"video_thruplay_watched_actions not available{ex}")
                        insight_thruplay='0'


                print(insight)
                ad_pf_insight_dict={
                    "account_id":insight['account_id'],
                    "account_currency":insight['account_currency'],
                    "account_name":insight['account_name'],
                    "actions":insight_action,
                    "ad_id":insight['ad_id'],
                    "adset_id":insight['adset_id'],
                    "adset_name":insight['adset_name'],
                    "campaign_id":insight['campaign_id'],
                    "campaign_name":insight['campaign_name'],
                    "clicks":insight['clicks'],
                    "date_start":insight['date_start'],
                    "date_stop":insight['date_stop'],
                    "objective":insight['objective'],
                    "publisher_platform":insight['publisher_platform'],
                    "spend":insight['spend'],
                    "action_values":insight_action_value,
                    "video_thruplay_watched_actions":insight_thruplay,
                    "impressions":insight['impressions']
                }
                print(ad_pf_insight_dict)
                platform_insights_async.append(ad_pf_insight_dict)
```